# What are the requirements for the reset password page for Realm Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, authentication, realm, maui, reset-password

I have set up user creation and authentication for a .net maui app using MongoDB and Realm, and it works brilliantly. I am struggling a bit with the reset password function. I have opted to use the “send a password reset email”

[image]

It then asks for a password reset url. This is where I get stuck. As I understand, this is the site that the password reset email will link to, and it will append a token to the end of the url. But I can’t seem to find any instructions on how to set up this page in a way that passes on the updated password and the token to Realm. Anyone care to point me in the right direction?

This may be an obvious thing to some of you, but I have very limited experience with authentication services.

I have tried to set it up with localhost:3000 for testing purposes, but obviously, it expects to find a page, and I don't have anything set up.

Comment: There are a couple of close votes but this is actually a good question and directly related to programming. The issue is the Realm Docs are vague at best on this topic. Details about how to perform a password reset using email auth are missing - yes, there there are steps but "the user is sent a URL Link" is vague; what URL link? "extract these query parameters from the user's unique URL"; when is the app notified of the changes? I don't believe Realm has implemented built in handling of this feature; you would need to set up a server with a password reset URL that can be sent to the user.

Comment: I have just found some more info on this at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/dotnet/manage-users/manage-email-password-users/
I will post a code sample when I've finished. Thanks for your help